# How to save qr code by generating in flask python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

How to save a unique qrcode image?

```
 <div class="input-container">
                <label for="college_id">College ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="college_id" name="college_id" placeholder="College ID" />
            </div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>

        <div class="form">
            <button type="button" onclick="generateQRCode()">
                Generate QR Code
            </button>
            <div id="qrcode-container" name="qrcode">
                <div id="qrcode" class="qrcode"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generateQRCode() {
        let college_id_code = document.getElementById("college_id").value;
        if (college_id_code) {
            let qrcodeContainer = document.getElementById("qrcode");
            qrcodeContainer.innerHTML = "";
            new QRCode(qrcodeContainer, college_id_code);
            document.getElementById("qrcode-container").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a unique college ID:");
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to save unique qrcode image in folder & by save folder by providing unique id.

Comment: There nothing to do with flask or python because you are generating Qr-code at front-end.

Comment: Then how can i solve by back-end can u provide me in details with code?

Comment: Hope this can help you :- https://dspyt.com/simple-qr-code-generator-on-aws-with-flask